# Некорректное появление печатающегося текста?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток. При скролле до нужного блока включается анимация печатающегося текста, но если скролить дальше анимация начинается заново, а нужно чтобы не возобновлялась. И текст ДАЛЕЕ должен появляться после того как допечатается текст. Спасибо. https://jsfiddle.net/76oushwm/17/

```js
$(function() {

  window.onscroll = function() {
    $('.animate__tippy').each(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.animate__tippy').offset().top - $(window).height() && $(window).scrollTop() <= $('.animate__tippy').offset().top) $('.animate__tippy').animate_Text();
    });
  }

  $.fn.animate_Text = function() {
    var string = this.text();
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.html(string.replace(/./g, '<span class="new">$&</span>'));
      $this.find('span.new').each(function(i, el) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(el).addClass('div_opacity');
        }, 40 * i);
      });
    });
  };
  $('.animate__tippy').animate_Text();
});
```

```css
.animate__content {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.animate__image {
  height: 500px;
}

.animate__tippy {
  width: 300px;
}

.animate__tippy .new {
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate__tippy .div_opacity {
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.animate__button {
  color: red;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="animate__content"></div>
<div class="animate__image">
  <div class="animate__tippy">
    Привет!Привет! Привет!Привет! Привет!Привет! Привет!Привет! ПриветПривет! Привет!Привет!
  </div>
  <div class="animate__button">ДАЛЕЕ</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пора выкидывать jQuery и брать IntersectionObserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе не хватает какой-то булевой переменной, что анимация уже запустилась:

```
let animationStarted = false;

if (!animationStarted && $(window).scrollTop() >= $('.animate__tippy').offset().top - $(window).height() && $(window).scrollTop() <= $('.animate__tippy').offset().top) {
    $('.animate__tippy').animate_Text();
    animationStarted = true;
}
```

И у тебя вычисления происходят каждый раз, когда скроллишь. Будет лучше если сделать так:

```
let animationStarted = false;
let top = $('.animate__tippy').offset().top - $(window).height()
let bottom = $('.animate__tippy').offset().top

if (!animationStarted && $(window).scrollTop() >= top && $(window).scrollTop() <= bottom) {
    $('.animate__tippy').animate_Text();
    animationStarted = true;
}
```